# Android Wear Build 1.0 - Automatically Uninstalls App

Tags: android, wear-os

I am currently testing an app on Android wear. If I push the app to wear using Android studio or ADBinstall then the application installs on the watch and remains there properly. However I am using the embeded apk wear 1.0 build strategy (embedding the wear apk inside phone apk), everything works fine when i install the phone app it also automatically installs the wear app. However the app installs on the wear, after 30 seconds or so the app automatically uninstalls from wear and the icon is removed.

This is a very strange issue and hard to pin point, would appreciate some help on this or any reason why this could be happening.

Comment: What version of Android Wear is running on the watch?

Comment: Wear 1.4, tested on moto 360 and Samsung Gear Live

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#wear-1x are you using a debug key? "Note: This feature doesn't work when you are signing your apps with a debug key. While developing, installing apps with adb install or Android Studio directly to the watch is required."

Comment: Using non debug key, generating build via assembleRelease. The technique also works, it does install the build, I can even launch the wear app and use it but for some reason after 30-45 seconds it automatically uninstalls the app without any warning what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

Found your question while fighting this issue myself... I like you have a wear apk bundled into my phone app's apk and have seen this behaviour. I think I've nailed the process to avoid it! First you want to set up release mode with a signing configuration (this is roughly what we have)

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias ''
        keyPassword ''
        storeFile file('../Store Info/app_key.jks')
        storePassword ''
        v1SigningEnabled true
        v2SigningEnabled false
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Then set all of your modules to build variant "release" in Android Studio. At this point you should be able to run the phone-side app only & have the watch side app automatically install. Then when it comes to release:

- Do a project clean
- Do one last install and run
- Navigate to "project_name/module_name/build/outputs/apk/" to find your application's APK
- Done

I guess other bits of advice I could provide are:

- adb -d uninstall  is great for uninstalling the app from both devices
- adb -d install  is great for testing your final build actually works
- Refuse the Google signing key management when uploading your APK to Google